# multilined pic caption with inline and colored background

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a headline caption on a pic with a (transparent) background. so far i've been rather unsuccessful: when adding "Inline" and "padding" the text shifts sans the white background, and the lines don't stay aligned to one side (when padding-left: 10px) - the upper line gets an indent. Also, when headline "breaks" I prefer that the background continues with 5 or so px beyond the last word on the line.

my html so far, which just creates a caption box with the same width as the pic.

```
<div class="img_box"><a title="January travel news" href=""><img src=".../pic.jpg" width="238" height="165"><span class="intro">January travel news</span></a></div>
```

and css

.img_box 
        {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 185px;
        height: 122px;
    }

```
.img_box img 
{
width: 185px;
height: 122px;
display: block;
            }


.img_box a 
{
    width: 185px;
    height: 122px;
    text-decoration: none;}

.img_box a span.intro {
        position: absolute;
        color: #000;
        line-height:12px;
        background: #fff;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        height: 25px;
        bottom: 15px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to make it look like?

Comment: like this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/75576539@N06/6791743181/in/photostream/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

The major change was to make the anchor position relative. What that does is make the span inside it positioned absolute relative to its parent (the anchor).

Also look at the jsfiddle I made for it.  http://jsfiddle.net/mLXda/

```
.img_box img {
  width: 185px;
  height: 122px;
  display: block;
}


.img_box a 
{
  width: 185px;
  height: 122px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; /* this is the most important line to add */
}

.img_box .intro {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    background: #eee;
    line-height:12px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 15px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```